# php_memcache.dll vc6 X64?

Tags: php, 64-bit, memcached

I am running wamp server with php 5.3.0. My efforts running memcached were a fail :(
After googeling I found out that the problem is that I need the correct php_memcache.dll
which is a vc6 compiled for windows 7 X64. Does anyone know where can I find the dll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running 64 bit:

The common service and extensions will not work for you.

Install the 64 bit memcached service:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.northscale.com/memcached-win64-1.4.4-14.zip

And one of these php extensions (to match your php version):

Php 5.3: http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?o60feet9sw71six

Php 5.4: http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?8d3vd26z3fg6bf1